# How to debug the error that's generated while building with ng build --prod?

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I have created an app and wanted to build it using `ng build --prod`. While I did so, I got an error message with the current version of syncfusion.

The following is the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns.es5.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
    at getJSDocTags (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13197:22)
    at getFirstJSDocTag (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13205:24)
    at Object.getJSDocTypeTag (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13154:19)
    at checkParenthesizedExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45628:56)
    at checkExpressionWorker (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45676:28)
    at checkExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)
    at checkBinaryLikeExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45155:29)
    at checkBinaryExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45147:20)
    at checkExpressionWorker (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45702:28)
    at checkExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)
    at checkExpressionCached (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45457:38)
    at getTypeOfExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45577:28)
    at checkDeclarationInitializer (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45469:24)
    at getTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30738:28)
    at getWidenedTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30961:24)
    at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrProperty (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31062:28)
ERROR in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars.es5.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
    at getJSDocTags (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13197:22)
    at getFirstJSDocTag (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13205:24)
    at Object.getJSDocTypeTag (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13154:19)
    at checkParenthesizedExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45628:56)
    at checkExpressionWorker (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45676:28)
    at checkExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)
    at checkBinaryLikeExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45155:29)
    at checkBinaryExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45147:20)
    at checkExpressionWorker (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45702:28)
    at checkExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)
    at checkExpressionCached (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45457:38)
    at getTypeOfExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45577:28)
    at checkDeclarationInitializer (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45469:24)
    at getTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30738:28)
    at getWidenedTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30961:24)
    at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrProperty (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31062:28)
ERROR in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs.es5.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
    at getJSDocTags (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13197:22)
    at getFirstJSDocTag (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13205:24)
    at Object.getJSDocTypeTag (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13154:19)
    at checkParenthesizedExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45628:56)
    at checkExpressionWorker (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45676:28)
    at checkExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)
    at checkBinaryLikeExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45155:29)
    at checkBinaryExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45147:20)
    at checkExpressionWorker (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45702:28)
    at checkExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)
    at checkExpressionCached (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45457:38)
    at getTypeOfExpression (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45577:28)
    at checkDeclarationInitializer (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45469:24)
    at getTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30738:28)
    at getWidenedTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30961:24)
    at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrProperty (F:\school-web-admin\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31062:28)
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile
```

.

The following is the dependency used for Syncfusion:

```
"@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^17.1.49",
"@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns": "^17.1.49",
"@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs": "^17.1.49",
"@syncfusion/ej2-angular-splitbuttons": "^17.1.47",
```

*NOTE: It runs successfully with just ng build.*

Comment: definitely looks like one of your dependencies...
`ERROR in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs.es5.js`

Maybe your configured to use `AOT` on prod build and this module doesn't support `AOT`?

Comment: no i did not use AOT during prod build

Comment: Maybe your issue is similar to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24577

Comment: I checked the same before posting the question, But there isnt' any @typedef in the js file.

Comment: have you reached out to @syncfusion? Isn't that a paid suite of tools? I'd expect you get some support with them right?

Comment: Faced the same issue when I use date range picker - did you find the solution for?
@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars.es5.js

Answer (score 0):

We checked the reported issue with the Syncfusion component mentioned, but we cannot reproduce the same in our end. We suspect that this issue is due to build-optimizer so we're asking you to share the details below to help you better.

```
angular-cli version 
@angular-devkit\build-optimizer version
```

However, we have created a sample for your reference that you can download form the link below.

Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/239187/ze/angular-apps-514191590

Please let us know if you have any other queries.

Regards,

Syncfusion Team